# Android Google Maps SDK, not filling circle if crosses north or south pole

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2, android-8.0-oreo

I tried code below to draw day/night circles on map :

```
circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(new LatLng(37.4, 85.0))
                .radius(100000)
                .strokeWidth(10)
                .strokeColor(Color.GREEN)
                .fillColor(Color.argb(128, 255, 0, 0))
                .clickable(true);
```

The problem is if radius is enough big so circle crosses either of poles, map sdk will not fill circle, but only draws outline stroke.

Answer (score 1):

This bug was reported in Google issue tracker in August 2017. You can find it here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64502178

Feel free to star the bug to add your vote and subscribe to notifications from Google. Hopefully one day they will fix this issue in future Google Play Services releases.